# Clocks at a moving reference frame

Tags: special-relativity, inertial-frames, time-dilation, observers

This is an example which I'm not grasping quite well in Special Relativity:

A train $S'$ is moving at speed $.5c$ with 3 clocks inside 1 meter apart. Someone on a resting platform (lab frame $S$) checks the time on those moving clocks precisely when $S$ coincides with the middle clock passing by, at which $t = t' = 0$.

The person on the resting platform ($S$) tries to read the time on the three clocks at $S'$. It considers the Lorentz Transformation $ct = \gamma (ct' +(v/c)x') = 0 \iff t' = -\frac{1}{2c}x'$ where $x' \in \{-1, 0, 1\}$.

But isn't $t'$ the time passing by in the $S'$ reference frame to $S'$ itself?

Comment: It is hard to tell what your question is. Do you think your result is wrong?

Comment: What does "read [the times] at $S'$ mean? $S'$ is a reference frame. Do you mean at $t'=0$?